# What does the word "conduit" mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

One of my favorite bands, Knuckle Puck, released a new album yesterday.
So, there is a track, named "Conduit" [(full lyrics here)](https://genius.com/Knuckle-puck-conduit-lyrics)

And the chorus there sounds like that:

> If all you are is under the surface
>
> Then why is it so hard to be a
> conduit?

In [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conduit) the meaning of *conduit* is

> NOUN
>
> **1** A channel for conveying water or other fluid. ‘nearby springs
> supplied the conduit which ran into the brewery’
>
> **1.1** A person or organization that acts as a channel for the transmission of something. ‘as an actor you have to be a conduit for
> other people's words’ More example sentences
>
> **2** A tube or trough for
> protecting electric wiring. ‘the gas pipe should not be close to any
> electrical conduit’ mass noun ‘the cable must be protected by conduit’

So, regarding this, it suppose to be mean some `person that acts as a channel for the transmission of something`.

But I don't really get it, what exactly it could mean here?

P.S. My apologies if it's really stupid question, just let me know, guys.

Comment: Any of the definitions will work, if you consider that it's a metaphor.  But I'm thinking that "conduit" has some added implications for those who deal is ghosts and spirits.  There may be some flavor of that in the song.

Comment: Lyrics are like poetry. There are multiple interpretations. Saying exactly what the word or song means by the word is off topic here, because we don’t do literary criticism. But you have the basic meaning correct, per your dictionary search.

Comment: In this context a 'conduit', I suspect, would refer to what mystics and spiritualists call a 'medium'.

Comment: @Clare Oh i see, but basic meaning here was kinda confusing in the way i understand it

Comment: @NigelJ cool, i guess you are right. Could you please post it as an answer

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Answer posted as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the meaning stated above 'a channel for the transmission of something' and the hint of allusion made in the lyric, it would seem that the word 'conduit' is being used in the meaning of what some would term 'a medium'. The reference is vague and it could be just an expression referring to humanity, generally, that humanity is a substantial conveyance and what is conveyed is a matter of spirit.